# PHP - How to replace string with php code?

Tags: php, string, variables, str-replace

I am very beginner in programmer, I am sorry if my question is crazy thing, but I am being crazy with it :D

I want to create an template for my php file (or replace my string with my php file):

my_string.html

```
{header}
Some String {foo} Some String {bar} Some String 
{footer}
```

my_file.php

```
<div class="header"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
<?php if(isset($foo)) { echo "FOO"; } ?>
<?php if(isset($bar)) { echo "BAR"; } ?>
<div class="footer">mywebsite.com</div>
```

Can I do something like this?

```
<?php $find = array("{header}", "{foo}", "{bar}", "{footer}"); ?>   
<?php $replace = array(
"<div class=\"header\"><img src=\"logo.png"\ /></div>",     
"<?php if(isset(\$foo)) { echo \"FOO\"; } ?>",
"<?php if(isset(\$bar)) { echo \"BAR\"; } ?>",
"<div class=\"footer\">mywebsite.com</div>"); ?>

<?php echo str_replace($find, $replace, implode("<br>", file("my_string.html"))); ?>
```

Results from my_file.php :

```
<div class="header"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
Some String FOO Some String BAR Some String 
<div class="footer">mywebsite.com</div>
```

Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Are you trying to create your own template system? The question isn't very clear.

Comment: @nus Yes, exactly.. I want to create an template for my_file.php

Comment: actually after trying another 20 captcha's, I'm positive that they don't even look at whether the answer is correct. I surely didn't get all the captcha's right, because they are absolutely unreadable, but I surely got some right. I'm done with trying to help people on stackexchange. bye

Comment: Hi @nus thanks for your answer, finally I resolved it.. I split my php file into some part file and join it again into a file..

Comment: Hi @AjieKurniyawan , welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we prefer to keep questions and answers separated. Thus I separated your answer in a wiki answer (I won't get reputation from it) so feel free to accept it. The best thing to do is you to properly answer your question in the form below and accept your own answer, so that other see the question is answered already.

Comment: Also, it's okay not to say `hi I'm ...` nor greetings; actually many programmers prefer it since it reduces the time spent in each question and it's the accepted behaviour here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I copied/pasted the OP answer here in a community wiki since it was appended to the question.**

I split my_file.php file to some part and then rejoin it again

header.php

```
<div class="header"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
```

foo.php

```
<?php if(isset($foo)) { echo "FOO"; } ?>
```

bar.php

```
<?php if(isset($bar)) { echo "BAR"; } ?>
```

footer.php

```
<div class="footer">mywebsite.com</div>

// Var

$header = implode("", file("header.php"));
$foo = implode("", file("foo.php")); 
$bar = implode("", file("bar.php")); 
$footer = implode("", file("footer.php")); 

// New template
$new_template = "new_template.php";

$find = array ("{header}",  "{foo}", "{bar}", "{footer}");
$replace = array ($header, $foo, $bar, $footer);

$contents = str_replace($find, $replace, implode("<br>", file("my_string.html")));
file_put_contents($new_template, $contents);

// Results
include $new_template;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
/**
 * Replace every pattern from the array that match in the subject with 
 * the given value
 * 
 * @$subject The string to search and replace.
 * @$replace_with Array with key Value like
 *      $replace_with = array('{pattern}' => 'Value', 'Foo' => 'BaR');
*/
function template_replace($subject, $replace_with)
{
    // checking
    if(null == $subject) return null;
    if( !is_array($replace_with) || count($replace_with) == 0)
    {
        return $subject;   
    }

    // iterate over the pattern <=> replacement
    foreach($replace_with as $pattern => $replacement)
    {

        $pattern = preg_quote($pattern);

        // Replace all matches to pattern
        $subject = preg_replace(
            "/$pattern/",
            $replacement,
            $subject
        );
    }
    return $subject;
} 

// -----------------


$template = "{header}
Some String {foo} Some String {bar} Some String 
{footer}";

$pattern = array(
    '{header}' => '<div class="header"><img src="logo.png" /></div>',
    '{foo}' => 'Foo',
    '{bar}' => 'Bar',
    '{footer}' => '<div class="footer">mywebsite.com</div>'
    );

$result = template_replace($template, $pattern);

echo $result;

/*
<div class="header"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
Some String Foo Some String Bar Some String 
<div class="footer">mywebsite.com</div>
*/
```

Comment: This php code `<?php if(isset($foo)) { echo "FOO"; } ?>` and `<?php if(isset($bar)) { echo "BAR"; } ?>` are just some example, my php code is more complex.. maybe it won't work with array like this: `$pattern = array(
    '{foo}' => 'Foo',
    '{bar}' => 'Bar',
    ...
    );`

Comment: If your pieces of code are long, put them in files and use `file_get_contents` to get them in the array or look at an existing template library I would say (there's plenty, why invent the hot water?).

Comment: @Wuiso, there is an error in your code. The patterns aren't valid regular expressions because { and } need to be escaped. You can use `preg_quote` to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you are trying make your own template system. I would use regular expressions:

```
$html         = file_get_contents( 'my_string.html' );

$replacements = array
(
    array( '/{header}/', 'your html code' )
  , // ... the next one
  , // ... and so on
);


foreach( $replacements as $tag )

   $html = preg_replace( preg_quote( $tag[ 0 ] ), $tag[ 1 ], $html );


echo $html;
```